# Focusing on an input Field when using <lightning:inputField>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-inputfield

I am using `lightning:recordEditForm` to display to users custom creation form and using `lightning:inputField`.

However, I am unable to set focus on a particular field.
I know that Salesforce doesn't support focus on `lightning:inputField` yet.
Salesforce has also said that using `lightning:input` inside `lighthing:recordEditForm` is not supported and hence, the focus will not work there as well. I have tried it and though the field is rendered focus doesn't work always.

My typical input field in the form looks like this

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="contact" fieldName="ContactId" value="{!v.contactId}" onchange="{!c.doSomething}"/>
```

Has anybody been able to make focus work with `lightning:inputField`?
Please note it has to work with pre-population.

Comment: Ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

Because [`lighnting:inputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation) does not support `focus` property, there's no way you will be able to achieve it.

Also as you cannot utilize `lightning:input` within a `lightning:recordEditForm`, the same way you could utilize `lightning:inputField`, e.g., data type, FLS are automatically taken care of while using `lightning:inputField` within the context of `lightning:recordEditForm`. In absence of those, your only option here will be to create a completely custom component utilizing `lightning:input` which supports the `focus` property and be able to focus on the respective element.

Aside from this, you should review how significant is your focus requirements vs. building anything custom.

Comment: can you please provide any documentation where `lightning:input` can not utilize with in `lighting:recordeditform`

Comment: To be very clear, cannot be utilized here refers to the *expected* behavior of the component within that context. E.g., rendering the exact field type. Having FLS implemented (enforced by `lightning:recordEditForm`). Let me make an edit to explicitly highlight what I meant.

Comment: yes i agree with that FLS and field data type are achieved by using `lightning:inputfield`.  but we can use `lighting:input` and `lighting:inputfield` mix with in `lightning:recordeditform`

Comment: Yes you can, and that's the *custom* approach that I am referring to here. That will lead you to take care of additional stuff just to achieve focus on the element.

Comment: @JayantDas: Salesforce has officially communicated to me via salesforce case and emails that `lightning:input` is not supported within the context of `lightning:recordEditForm`. So using `lightning:input` gives mixed results in terms of focus and I am better off in not using it. The cost of designing an entirely custom with only `lightning:input` is huge and nobody will pay for it. The requirement of focus is very urgent and lack of this feature has resulted in a lot of negative feedback with customers switching back to classic.

Comment: @maniaccoder I have highlighted that in my answer. Unfortunately other than a custom approach there’s no other option.

Answer (score 0):

i just tweak `lighting:recordeditform` for research. since i couldn't find any where in documentation for `lighting:recordeditform` doesn't support for `lightning:input` so i tried with below code for set the focus for `lighting:input` with in `lighting:recordeditform`

cmp

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">

<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact'}"/>

<!-- Display the new contact form -->
<div class="Create Contact">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:new_contact" title="Create Contact">
        <lightning:recordEditForm
                                  onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                                  onerror ="{!c.handlerror}"
                                  objectApiName="Contact">
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="AssistantName" value="{!v.newContact.AssistantName}"></lightning:inputField>
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Age__c" value="{!v.newContact.Age__c}"></lightning:inputField>
            <lightning:input label="email" type="email" aura:id="emailfld" value="{!v.newContact.Email}"></lightning:input>
            <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" name="update" type="submit" label="Save"  />
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </lightning:card>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
({
handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Prepare a new record from template
    event.preventDefault();
     var newcon = component.get("v.newContact");
     var newconstr = JSON.stringify(newcon); //newconstr = "{"sobjectType":"Contact","AssistantName":"setesting","Age__c":"32"}"
    component.find("emailfld").focus();
},

})
```

[image]

Comment: You have written focus method in "handleSubmit" which will be invoked when user submits the form.
The requirement is to focus on the field as soon as its loaded so that the user doesn't have to scroll to correct field.
You won't find the documentation about lightning:input not been supported in lightning:recordEditForm as salesforce communicated this to me in an email.

Answer (score 0):

OK thanks for the conversation here.  It allowed me to come up with an out-of-the-box solution.  Basically you have to create a `lightning-input` field and give it focus, then have Javascript which copies the value `onblur` to your `lightning-input-field`.  Sample code:

HTML

```html
<lightning-input label="First Name" data-element="first-name" onblur={updateName}>
</lightning-input>

<lightning-input-field field-name="FirstName" data-element="first-name-field" class="slds-hide">
</lightning-input-field>
```

Controller

```js
hasRendered = false;

renderedCallback() {
    if (this.hasRendered) return;
    const inputBox = this.template.querySelector('[data-element="first-name"]');
    if (inputBox) {
      inputBox.focus();
    }
    this.hasRendered = true;
  }

updateName() {
    const firstName = this.template.querySelector('[data-element="first-name"]').value;
    this.template.querySelector('[data-element="first-name-field"]').value = firstName;
  }
```

Comment: Shane I had posted this question in the context of Aura components and not Lightning Web Components.
Since, the start of this year I have also switched the components to LWC.